# Dual-SSD laptop - should I move the pagefile to the non-boot SSD?

Tags: windows-7, hard-drive, ssd, pagefile

I have 2 SSDs in my laptop of equal (256GB) size. After reading [this Technet article](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/ff382717.aspx) I'm tempted to do what it suggests and move my paging file to the other (non-boot) drive. Is this worth doing? Are there any consequences I should be aware of or should I just leave things as they are?

Comment: How much RAM does your laptop have? You could possibly shrink the pagefile if you have enough RAM.

Comment: It's got 8GB ...

Comment: Do you want to move the pagefile to prolong the life of the ssd or to speed up things?

Comment: As it says in the article, I would split the pagefile to both SSD's. For _most_ users, I would say you could shrink it to about a GB per SSD and be fine.